# How to get minified js/css file name in angular 2 (v.6)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way to get the minified file name programmatically in angular 6 ?

Example: after ng build, it is generating something like this:

`styles.ec7286a7eee694c180a3.css`

In my component I want to be able to get that particular name:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-get-style',
  templateUrl: './get-style.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-style.component.scss']
})
export class GetStyleComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {
     //get the minified file name
     // alert -> styles.ec7286a7eee694c180a3.css
   }
}
```

Comment: The component its-self doesn't have such information at its disposal. Cause the hash at the end of the file name is generated at build time. So (as advised in an answer below by @David)  the only way to get this information is to loop through resources that are being loaded as part of your page and see if any of them is similar to what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Alexus pointed out in the comment, the file name is generated the during build process so you have no way of knowing it apart from checking all css/js files at runtime.

Otherwise, you could try removing output hashing in your build process (`ng build --output-hashing=none`)

Exemple to dynamically identify a given js/css file:

**js file**

```
let nameToFind = 'styles';
//get all script tags (change to 'styles' if needed)
let scriptTags = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'));

//filter to get tag whose src attribute starts with styles
let targetElt= scriptTags.filter(c => c.hasAttribute('src') && 
               c.getAttribute('src').startsWith(nameToFind))[0];

console.log(targetElt.getAttribute('src'));
```

**css file**

```
let nameToFind = 'styles';
let linkTags = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('link'));
let targetElt= linkTags .filter(c => c.hasAttribute('href') && 
               c.getAttribute('href').startsWith(nameToFind))[0];

console.log(targetElt.getAttribute('href'));
```